# Annotations or Block comments first? (Commenting Style)

Tags: java, annotations, comments

```
/* Prints the coordinate */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return new StringBuilder("(").append(x).append(",").append(y).append(",").append(z).append(")").toString();
}
```

In the above example the comments for the method came first. Is this what is usually done, or is the reverse the accepted practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though its completely a matter of choice or rather say will be decided by team coding conventionn but I personally feel following one looks way better and expressive:

```
/**
  comments
  .... 
*/
@Annotation
type method(){
    ...
    ...
 }
```